# Using template struct in vector with deffrent types

Tags: c++, templates

Hello this my c++ source

```
template <typename T>
struct Key
{
    string Name;
    T Value;
};

struct Block
{
    string Name;
    vector <Key> Keys; // I got error here ... !!!!
};

int main()
{
    Block thisBlock;

    Key <bool> Key1;
    Key <string> Key2;

    // Set key 1
    Key1.Name = "Key1";
    Key1.Value = false;

    // Set key 2
    Key2.Name = "Key2";
    Key2.Value = "Hey";

    // Set block with all keys
    thisBlock.Name = "Block1";
    thisBlock.Keys.push_back(Key1);
    thisBlock.Keys.push_back(Key2);

    return 0;
}
```

please guide me about this error ! i know i have to use `<>` in `vector <Key>` but if i do this, my block keys is limit to that type only ! is there any way to fix this problem?

**Error**

```
argument list for class template "Key" is missing (in block struct (vector <key>>)
```

Comment: It should be something like `std::vector<Key<bool>> Keys;`. But you cannot add different types of `Key` in your Block as you do.

Comment: i know that but i have string, int and ... types !!! it's not only bool ! so i can't set Specified type !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Key<bool>` and `Key<string>` are two different types, unrelated one to another, so, you cannot store both of them in one `std::vector`, just like you cannot create a `std::vector` storing both `int` and `float`.

To solve this issue, you could create a common base class for your keys, something like this:

```
class KeyBase {
public:
    virtual ~KeyBase() = default;               // virtual destructor to avoid memory leaks
    std::string GetName() const { return name; }// some common functions
    virtual std::string ToString() const = 0;   // and some function to be overriden
    std::string name;                           // and members

    KeyBase(std::string name_) : name(name_) {};
    KeyBase() = default;
};

template<class T>
class Key : public KeyBase {
public:
    std::string ToString() const override { ... } // implementation of virtual functions
    T value;
};

...
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<KeyBase>> vk;
vk.push_back(std::make_unique<Key<bool>>());
vk.push_back(std::make_unique<Key<string>>());
std::cout << vk[0]->GetName() << ' ' << vk[1]->GetName(); // Works
std::cout << vk[0]->value << ' ' << vk[1]->value; // Does not work as KeyBase has no value
std::cout << dynamic_cast<Key<bool>*>(vk[0].get())->value; // Works as vk[0] is now casted
```

`std::unique_ptr` used here is a smart pointer type - it's semantics are just like the pointer, but it `delete`s the storing object when is `delete`d, making memory management much easier. Also it's important here that the `std::vector` stores pointer to `KeyBase`, and not `KeyBase`. This is done to avoid object slicing.

Also, please use `std::dynamic_cast` with caution: it will return `nullptr` if you try to cast to an incorrect type.

**UP**: To set the value during the `push_back` operation, one way is to use the helper function and setting constructor:

```
template<typename T>
class Key : public KeyBase {
    ...
    Key(T val) : value(val) {}
    Key(T val, std::string name) : KeyBase(name), value(val) {}
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Key<T>> createKey(T value) {
    return std::make_unique<Key<T>>(value);
}
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Key<T>> createKey(T value, std::string name) {
    return std::make_unique<Key<T>>(value, name);
}

...
vk.push_back(createKey<bool>(false));
vk.push_back(createKey<string>("abc"));
```

Actually, with such approach you could even omit the type name, like this:

```
vk.push_back(createKey(1, "abc")); // creates Key<int> with value 1 and name "abc"
```

But be extra careful with such omission, for example, `"abc"` has type `const char*` and so `createKey("abc")` will create `Key<const char*>`.

Comment: @Samethings `ToString()` is just an example of a function you may need in `KeyBase`. Fell free to remove it or implement in any way you wish.

Comment: @Samethings Actually, multiple `dynamic_cast`s are a sign of bad design (specifically, probable violation of Liskov Substitution Principle). If sensibly possible, you should use virtual functions instead. Speaking of this particular example, you if you want to do something with `Key<T>` depending on `T`, consider writing this code as a member function in `Key<T>` class. Also, having a `std::vector` of very different types looks suspicious, so, if you can store them in some other way, that would also probably make your code better.

Comment: how can i get the value like this v[0]->getValue<bool>(); ??? i know i have to set dynamic_cast<Key<bool>*>(vk[0].get())->value; into template but i don't know how !

Comment: Brilliant! ABSOLUTELY BRILLIANT !!!
How can't I think up this solution !!!!

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 And I wanna ask, how to determine which type should be dynamic_cast back? In your example, you know exactly vk[0] is bool because you push_back it yourself. But how do you determine this run-time ?

Comment: @Shih-Chan Huang There's the `typeid` operator, which returns the run-time type information. Or you could store a separate id of the object type. Or you could try casting the object to different types and select the one which returns not `nullptr`

Answer (score 1):

If `Block` is to use a generic `Key`, you must make it a template as well:

```
template <typename T>
struct Block
{
    string Name;
    vector <Key <T>> Keys;
};
```

Addressing the more general problem, *i.e.* that you want to store objects of different type in the same vector, will require something like [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
struct Block
{
    std::string Name;
    std::vector <std::variant<bool, std::string>> Keys;
};
```

For pre-C++17, the Boost libraries have [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/variant.html) and [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/any.html) which do the same thing.

Comment: My block have so many keys with deffrents types !!! if i set one block with <bool>, i can't set string or int key inside it !

Comment: @Samethings: Correct. Since `Key<bool>` is a type distinct from `Key<string>`, you cannot store them in the same vector. What you want is the algebraic types (`std::any`, `std::variant`) available in C++17.

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: @Samethings: I don't know how to explain it more clearly, because I don't know what part you are misunderstanding. Do you know what a type is, and how the C++ type system works?

Comment: @You Unfortunately, most modern compilers still don't support C++17. There're also such types in `boost` library.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: Good point, added links to `boost::variant` and `boost::any`. Both `libstdc++` and `libc++` have pre-standardization implementations, though (in their preview releases, IIRC).